# Error while running Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new to android, i've wriiten a code for printing 'Hello World' which will show the result in emulator but there is a strange problem, which i'm unable to understand. please help me
here is the error

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
### WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Warning: No DNS servers found
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
Unknown cp14 write op1:6 crn:0 crm:8 op2:6
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xff91c756
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.1.7'
R00=00000000 R01=000005a1 R02=00000100 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00010010 R15=ff91c756
PSR=400001f3 -Z-- T svc32
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Now please help me what i can do in it.. It is all so complicated for me.

Comment: Try restarting your emulator

Comment: try creating different AVD and running them

Comment: @MarkShen i've alreday tried it 10 times but again same output

Comment: @Shubhank i've tried this also but that AVD too is is giving same error

Comment: which OS are you on ?

Comment: @Shubhank i'm using Windows 10 64bit

Comment: you can try genymotion emulator. that is a good alternate for emulator

Comment: @Shubhank & where can i get emulator, i mean how can i access to that emulator ?

Comment: a vid tutorial explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byMla9XKk2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already try disabling Hyper-V? If you didn't, you should do that, since the AVD is not compatible with Hyper-V.

If you're using Windows, you need to open a command prompt with administrator rights.
Enter following command then:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

Comment: How could i do it.. please can you explain me further

Comment: @Dimple Edited my answer

Comment: again same error nothing is happening.. any other way soo please tell me

Comment: @Dimple No problem! Good luck finding a solution to this problem!